# How to use reCaptcha on different forms of a single page

Tags: php, recaptcha

I want to use reCaptcha on different forms of a single page.
I tried [this way](http://mycodde.blogspot.in/2014/12/multiple-recaptcha-demo-same-page.html) but it's not working.Generated multiple captchas but $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] value is not getting.

Is there any way to specify different names for each reCaptchas?

Please suggest any solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You share wrong url on **this way**

Comment: @Rahautos edited my question.Please check now.